# passport.authenticate injects null object for request in google login

Tags: node.js, express, google-signin, passport.js

I'm using Express + Passport for Google authentication for my application.

Here is my route:

```
const authCallback = function(req, res) {
    if (req.user._id) {
        if (abc()) { return res.redirect('/app'); }

        res.redirect('/profile/' + req.user._id.toString());
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
};

app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', authCallback));
```

I'm getting an error **Cannot read property 'user' of null** at line 1 in `authCallback` function.

I tried debugging this but couldn't find a solution.

Please let me know if more code is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

auth callback should not have req,res . it returns `function(err, user, info) { }):`

```
  const authCallback = function(err, user,info) {
        if (user._id) {
            if (abc()) { return res.redirect('/app'); }

            res.redirect('/profile/' + user._id.toString());
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    };

    app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', authCallback));
```

Comment: This helps but the exact problem was, I wanted to pass a callback to express get function but was passing the callback to passport function. You solution helped me find that problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answer from Dinesh.

This solved the problem exactly.

```
app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google'), authCallback);
```

instead of

```
app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', authCallback));
```

The callback is meant to be passed to express get API but is being passed to passport API.